# i have a function 'filter' which is suppose to filter data from firestore based on name. I am able to get the whole data from firestore

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, collections, google-cloud-firestore

My challenge is in the collection reference in my function. My collection is like 'users/user.id/mat'is this the correct way of doing this. Please help

```
filter(){
    this.mat = this.afs.collection('users/user.id/mat', ref => ref.where('name','==','testUID')).valueChanges()
    console.log(this.mat);
    return this.mat
   }
```

Comment: you have to subscribe to the `valueChanges()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to subscribe to the `valueChanges()`:

```
this.afs.collection('users/user.id/mat', ref => ref.where('name','==','testUID')).valueChanges().subscribe(response =>{
    if(response){
       console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. is 'user/user.id/mat' the right way of referencing my collection.

Comment: Not sure! I am not good at the firebase, you can refer firebase tutorial for that